# How to render .map() val and key as a prop outside of setState callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, ecmascript-6

I have this component which performs a `post request` and maps json data that I get in return. On this response I do `setState` and map the data in the callback. I do this because of setState's async nature.

I want to be able to use `val` and `key` outside of it's scope in `render()` but I'm not sure how to achieve this.

LoadCard:

```
class LoadCard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      req: [],
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.post(hostname, {
      request: "?request=getObjects"
    })
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          req: JSON.parse(response.data)
        },
          () => this.state.req.objects.map((val, key) => {
            // after mapping what to do here?
          })
        );
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log("Error: Card/componentDidMount: " + error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Card key={key} title={val.name} /> /* use val and key here */
    );
  }
}
```

In the component's render I want to be able to use `val` and `key` as a prop for `Card` component.

Card:

```
class Card extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View key={this.props.key}>
        <Text>{this.props.title}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Edit to fit comment question:

The response data I get returned looks like this:

```
{
    "objects": [
        {
            "zone_id_1": 151,
            "zone_id_2": null,
            "blocked": "Y",
            "type_id": 1,
            "name": "Alarm chauffeurs@ON=100",
            "output_value": 0,
            "object_id": 1,
            "input_value": 100,
            "last_changed": "2019-04-04T11:36:53",
            "continuously_high_enabled": "N"
        },
        {
            "zone_id_1": 150,
            "zone_id_2": null,
            "blocked": "N",
            "type_id": 1,
            "name": "Alarm office@ON=0",
            "output_value": 0,
            "object_id": 2,
            "input_value": 0,
            "last_changed": "2019-03-26T15:52:01",
            "continuously_high_enabled": "N"
        },

    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should run that inside your render function, this will be triggered once your setState has been finished.

Your state should have handle pre-data, and after getting data to have the same structure. Or do if validation in render method to check if values exist, but that's a waste of a couple of lines of code.

- default state: {data: []} // Initializing state - array
- on setState({data: req.objects}) // in your axios response - array with
  values

And your render should access it

```
  render() {
      const { data } = this.state;
      const Cards = data.map(({title}, key) => {
          return <Card key={key} title={title} />
      })
    
      return(
         <View>
           {Cards}
         </View>
      )
    }
```

Since you are using "req" state inside render function, it will automatically update as req value in the state is updated.

React is a very powerful tool, and I think everyone should read on how it works and why does it work the way it does.

Comment: I've tried it this way but I get error `"TypeError: Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.req.objects.map')`.

Comment: Logging `this.state.req` in the console prints an empty array at first: `05-03 15:55:32.400  5483  7757 I ReactNativeJS: []` and then follows with another log where setting state was succesfull

Comment: This is what led me to believe I tried to map over an empty state and had to wait for state to finish by mapping in callback.

Comment: Yes, just saw your state, you should really set your state to have some default empty array values in the beginging, eg req: {objects:[]}, so the code wont have unexpected errors. You get error undefined, since at first req is array, and key "objects" is notwhere to be found :)

Comment: I've just seen your updated response, I will try it out thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution worked. As to learning React, I try to read docs as much as possible but due to English not being my primary language, understanding such technical terms is hard for me. What learning source would you suggest for my situation?

Comment: Glad to help, just slowly going through their documentation will really help you a lot. But buying pluralsight or some other learn online site will do the trick. If not, check out LearnCode.academy on youtube and his video tutorials, he is really detailed and he explains it really nicely.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misunderstanding the behavior of `setState` here.
Do not map over `this.state.req.objects` in the `setState` callback.

Instead do :

```
class Card extends Component {
  render() {
    return this.state.req.objects.map((val, key) => (
      <View key={key}>
        <Text>{val.title}</Text>
      </View>
    ));
  }
}
```

Obviously, make sure your state is initialized correctly. For example, add a `objects: []` to `req`.